# Ubuntu 18.04 "No wifi adapter found"

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hardware

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on a Hewlett-Packard Pavilion dv6-3050us Entertainment Notebook. For nearly 2 years this has worked fine but suddenly I can get no internet. My hardware switch, which used to toggle between internet **on** or **off**, now toggles between airplane mode and nothing.

If I click on activities and Wi-Fi I get a message `no Wi-Fi adapter found`.  `iwconfig` returns `lo no wireless extensions`.  `lspci -nnk` does not include a network controller in its output list.  `sudo lshw -C network` returns blank.

I would be grateful for advice, and for any comments on what may have caused this.

Update 15 May - thank you for your contributions, K7AAY and Czar

ubuntu-drivers devices returns nothing.

I have followed (1) of the link you posted, Czar, but disconnecring the battery and holding the power button down has no effect.

(4) of that link - the HP website tells me that it does not provide drivers for my machine for any OS apart from Windows.

(6) of that link - I do not know how to reseat a wireless card.

You asked whether I had installed Ubuntu 20.04.  I haven't, but might that solve the problem?

I'm not sure what you mean by changing the kernel from my grub menu.  If I restart in recovery mode, or using Linux 4.15.0-96-generic, the problem persists.

I could buy a USB wifi adapter, but are there other things I could try first please?

Comment: There are multiple dv6 machines. What is the model part number from the serial number sticker? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a bad pcie wifi module. Lets get some info and here are some things to try:

Did you upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04? Try `ubuntu-drivers devices` and if you have a driver available then install with `sudo apt-get install *xxxxdriverxxxx*`

Does the problem exist if you change the kernel from you grub menu during boot?

Try steps 1, 4 (bios update) and 6 from https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/HP-pavilion-dv6-1390ev-wireless-not-working/td-p/1843501

Create a Live-USB of Ubuntu and check if it works? If it doesn't then it's probably hardware issue not software. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started

Purchase USB WiFi adapter as a replacement. I own several $5 ones that I use for troubleshooting. I've only had issues with AC speed USB adapters on Linux. Difficulties with compiling drivers with limited manufacturer linux support. Most time the cheap stuff works on Linux just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xubuntu on a HP entertainment dv9000. Wireless did not work. Situation may be similar. Found -to be the OEM wireless card which hadn't worked for a couple of years with the preinstalled Windows.  Apparently this was a common problem for HP around 2008-10 with the AMD Turion 64x2 processor causing causing an issue/overheat damage with the installed Wifi card - a broadcomm 802.11g network adaptor I believe.

A TP Link Archer T2 Plus USB wifi USB adaptor works for me.  Here's the setup on this laptop that works:

**HP Pavilion dv9000, AMD Turion 64x2 2.2Ghz**, upgraded RAM to 2x2GB 667 SODIMM [4GB total], NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150.

Installed **Xubuntu 22.04LTS** from USB.

Updated software over ethernet cable. Opened advanced network connection window. Inputed wireless name and password [probably could have done this later in the process]

Plugged in **Tp Link Archer** wifi.

Updated software packages. Unplugged ethernet cable. Advanced network connection automatically went from ethernet to the TPLink wifi since network connection had been preconfigured for our wifi..